# Unable to inspect Celery with SQS Backend

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm using Celery to process asynchronous tasks, and I'm using SQS on Amazon as my messaging server. My tasks have suddenly stopped processing, and when I went to inspect the Celery queue with:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
i.scheduled()
```

I received the error:

```
SQSError: SQSError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code><Message>Can only include alphanumeric characters, hyphens, or underscores. 1 to 80 in length</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>adbc0bc9-d1e2-5ab7-bd59-5a7a20cb876c</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

What's causing this? Clearly, this means that I'm passing it a parameter that's invalid, but since Celery is the one generating the SQS request, I'm unsure what that is. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `rdb` to debug?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this github](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3197) issue:

> Basically you can't inspect the state of any woker in the cluster.

Due to the fact that ([from the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html)):

> SQS doesn’t yet support worker remote control commands.

So for now this seems to not be possible - your best bet (and how I solved my problem that lead me here) is probably directly accessing the queue using boto3.